# Performance Improvement Plan, but no final outcome on the final day

Tags: management, work-environment

A friend of mine was placed on a PIP 7 weeks ago despite his having approached his manager about the lack of support he's been receiving from his team leader. He confided in me with this knowing I had been on one of these some years ago with another organization.

He had six weeks to "improve", by which he has improved, even though he had already made up his mine to move on from his current role. The day of when he would find out the final verdict as to whether he would stay or go (Jan 31) came and went, with nothing. No meeting, no email, no verdict. So he's still currently working at the company...

By comparison When I went through my PIP with another organization in 2016, I received an email, as well as a meeting to determine my scenario and received an official verdict.

He's not sure whether this was a case of them applying scare tactics to keep him in line, poor employee management or just bullying... I'm not sure what this could be myself. My friend is working for a small company with no HR department. Either way, he's seriously considering moving on from the company due to the lack of support he's been getting.

Would anyone have any idea what may be going on in the case of the PIP just stopping without an official outcome? I'd like to tell him something but given I didn't have this kind of outcome when I went through my PIP, I'm not sure what to compare this to.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

**People forget stuff and things are abandoned**

My benefit plan login took extra time as the enrolment forms got lost by the insurance company.

I got an offer letter in my email with no other context elevating me to permanent employee.

A friend of mine worked at a company where they hired a job 4 times because they kept on forgetting that a candidate had been selected due to turnover in the HR department. So 4 times they posted the same job application, interviewed candidates, had instructions from the relevant manager to extend an offer to a person and they dropped the ball three times. The job went unfilled for his entire contract with them.

Most people have a limited ability to keep track of things. I suspect the company just forgot. He should still leave, but he has had a stay of execution. They can pay his salary while he looks to escape.

Comment: Or...It’s a the Tuesday and there are 3 additional days in the work week.  Jan 31 was a Friday.  The next two days were the weekend.  Asking for the outcome is reasonable

Comment: @Donald remember that one of the potential (and most likely) outcomes is getting fired. The other possible outcome is the status quo. What is the benefit of reminding the company when he can collect a paycheque while he job hunts?

Comment: Asking is better than worrying about it.

Comment: Doesn't sound to me like he's worried about it. Perplexed maybe, not worried. And no, between living in Limbo, but still getting paid while looking for an escape hatch, and being out that same moment, with nothing... not knowing and collecting pay is **wayyyyy** better than the alternative. Would you deliberately ask in such a position, where, it's not even 50-50, more like 99-1, that you're out the moment you ask? I wouldn't and I suspect you wouldn't either!

Comment: @O.F. As the OP, I can tell you my friend is both perplexed and worried. Having been down this path myself, were I in my friend's shoes, I'd rather have been called in and had the verdict... He hasn't received one, and that "irks" him (his words). So understandably he's still looking to move on. To me, it still seems like the company are playing him... but I can't just tell my friend that...

But yes, collecting a paycheck regardless while looking is still a better option at this point than asking... (IMHO)